# Encode a string to UTF-8 format

Tags: sql-server, utf-8

I am trying to encode/decode a variable in SQL Server 2012. I am able to decode the variable, but when I was trying to encode it with the decoded value it was not showing the same value.

```
DECLARE @DecodedVal VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @EncodedVal VARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @NewDecodeVal VARCHAR(500)

 --//decode
SET @DecodedVal= N'SW5mb3JtYXRpb25zIHN1ciBsZXMgY29uZsOpcmVuY2VzIHTDqWzDqXBob25pcXVlcw=='

SET @EncodedVal = (
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), CONVERT(XML, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), CONVERT(XML, @DecodedVal).value('.', 'varbinary(max)'))))
    )

SELECT @EncodedVal

--//encode
SET @NewDecodeVal = (SELECT CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(xs:hexBinary(sql:column("bin")))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') Base64Encoding
FROM (  SELECT CAST(@EncodedVal AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS bin) AS bin_sql_server_temp)

SELECT @NewDecodeVal
```

Comment: AFAIK, SQL Server 2012-2017 only (properly) supports UTF-8 on certain Windows collations. This only returns SQL collations on SQL Server 2019: `SELECT Name, Description FROM fn_helpcollations() WHERE Name LIKE '%_UTF8';`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way to get my solutions for sql server 2012?